# How do I create a single script file for when I do and don't want to collect TensorBoard statistics?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I want to have a single script, that either collects tensorboard data or not, depending on how I run it. I am aware that I can pass flags to tell my script how I want it to be run. I could even hard code it in the script and just manually change the script.

Either solution has a bigger problem. I find myself having to write an if statement everywhere on my script when I want the summary writer operations to be ran or not. For example I find that I would have to do something like:

```
if tb_sys_arg = 'tensorboard':
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

and then depending on the value of `tb_sys_arg` run the summaries or not, as in:

```
if tb_sys_arg = 'tensorboard':
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
else:
    train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(tensorboard_data_dump_train, sess.graph)
```

this seems really silly to me. I'd rather not have to do that. Is this the right way to do this? I just don't want to collect statistics each time I run my main script but I also don't want to have two separate scripts either.

---

As an anecdotical story, few months ago I started using TensorBoard and it seems I have been running my main file as follow:

```
python main.py —logdir=/tmp/mdl_logs
```

so that it collects tensorboard data. But realized that I don't think I need that last flag to collect tensorboard data. Its been so long that now I forget if I actually need that. I've been reading the documentation and tutorials but it seems I don't need that last flag (its only needed to run the web app as in `tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory`, right?) Have I been doing this wrong all this time?

Comment: You can launch Supervisor without "summary" service, so it won't run the summary nodes: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard6/tf.train.Supervisor.md#launching-fewer-services

Comment: The flag you use is not strictly needed, but it allows to specify where to save the logs for TensorBoard, so it does have some use at training time. You could name it otherwise too.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov how about posting an answer with your link and the meaningful piece of code (`sv = Supervisor(logdir='/tmp/mydir', summary_op=None)`). You are spot on.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov yes! Please provide an answer with piece of code! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can launch Supervisor without "summary" service, so it won't run the summary nodes, see "Launching fewer services" section of the Supervisor docs --  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard6/tf.train.Supervisor.md#launching-fewer-services